# aggregate columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame as follows: 
 x1 ,x2, x3 are column's name

```
x1 x2 x3
A  c  d
A  e  f
B  z  f
B  z  f
B  d  e
```

I want to count the number of column x2 and x3 according to x1 
Such as following table:

```
   x1 x2 x3
    A  2  2
    B  2  2
```

I have tried as follows: 
library(plyr)
df3<-count(df, "x1","x2",x3) 
But it give me an error `Error in Summary.factor`
And Also I have tried this Approach

```
library(dplyr)
    df %>% select(x1,x2,x3)
     group_by(df$x1) %>%
      mutate(unique_types = n_distinct(df$x2,df$x3))
```

But it does not work.

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(x1) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(x2:x3), funs(n_distinct))
`

Comment: Thanks it works very well. so we should use summarise_at function including the n_distinct to omit the duplicated values.

Comment: I am not sure how many other columns you have in your dataframe. `summarise_at` is used to specify for which columns we want to get distinct values. If you have only 3 columns `df %>% group_by(x1) %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)` would also work. `n_distinct` basically returns number of unique values and here as we are grouping it by `x1` it returns number of unique values for each `x1` for `x2` and `x3` columns.

Comment: Thanks for clarification very helpful.